# Could a .svg be loaded twice in webpack?

Tags: svg, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, webpack-2

In my vue2.0 project, I had had .svg files loaded by "svg-sprite-loader".

But in  iconfont I introduced .svg too, so that some .svg files were loaded twice,which resulted an error in compiling.

So could a .svg be loaded twice in webpack,if I really had this requirement?

codes are as below

```
 [
    {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
      include: [resolve('src/icons')],        
      options: {
        symbolId: 'icon-[name]'
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
      loader: 'url-loader',     
      options: {
        limit: 10000,
        name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
      }
    }
 ]
```

Comment: What exact error message are you receiving?

Comment: @Stephan-v the error is                                                                                                         
`error   in ./src/icons/font/iconfont.svg?t=1534305396683

Module build failed: InvalidSvg: svg-sprite-loader exception.

module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "static/fonts/iconfont.8387278.svg";
    at Object.loader (E:\wendy\workplace\qlbank\web\node_modules\_svg-sprite-loader@3.5.2@svg-sprite-loader\lib\loader.js:34:11)`

Comment: if i really need it ,how could it be resolved?

Comment: `@font-face {font-family: "iconfont";
  src: url('iconfont.eot?t=1534305396683'); /* IE9*/
  src: url('iconfont.eot?t=1534305396683#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('iconfont.svg?t=1534305396683#iconfont') format('svg');
   /* iOS 4.1- */
}`